# PDO's fetch method passes wrong parameter to constructor class (in Yii)

Tags: pdo, yii, yii1.x

Model class MyModel has following behavior

```
public function behaviors() {
        return [
            'CTimestampBehavior' => [
                'class' => 'zii.behaviors.CTimestampBehavior',
                'createAttribute' => null,
                'updateAttribute' => 'update_time',
                'setUpdateOnCreate' => true
            ]
        ];
    }
```

In code, in controller I write something like

```
$model = new MyModel();
$dataReader = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
    ->selectDistinct('some fields')
    ->from('MyModel')
    ->leftJoin('some table')
    ->where('some criteria')
    ->query();
while ($item = $dataReader->readObject('MyMode', $model->getAttributes())) {
    **//!!! HERE item array is with model attributes, which are empty**
    $items[] = $item;
}
```

disaster, it's not working, items is array, each of element holding empty list of attributes, like no data fetched from db

If I write

```
$dataReader = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
    ->selectDistinct('some fields')
    ->from('MyModel')
    ->leftJoin('some table')
    ->where('some criteria')
    ->query();
while ($item = $dataReader->readObject('MyModel', MyModel::model()->getAttributes())) {


//!!! HERE item array is with model attributes, which hold correct data, taken from db
    $items[] = $item;
}
```

it's working

If I get rid off CTimestamp behavior, both cases work.

If I debug first case, I realize that, after pdo fetchobject is done, it calls constructor with scenario="current_timestamp()". Question is why? And where I missstepped?

Answer (score 1):

If you read [`readObject()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbDataReader#readObject-detail) documentation you will find that second argument is not list of fields, but list of constructor arguments. `CActiveRecord` has only one constructor argument - `$scenario`. `$dataReader->readObject('MyMode', $model->getAttributes())` essentially assigns random value as scenario, since it will get first value from `$model->getAttributes()`. In your case you probably need:

```
$item = $dataReader->readObject('MyModel', []);
```

Comment: There is not explicitly mentioned that readObject is a list of constructor arguments, moreover its list of fields - I'm pretty sure it's a list of model`s fields, attributes. And if ActiveRecord accepts only one argument scenario, why would I send a list? (Maybe there is other cases such as descendant, etc. it's not important actually in terms of this question).

Comment: Your answer is good and respectful. however it does not work. You can try on your own. I got the idea of this, and tried to put [null], and it worked. Hovewer, in this case it returns a model instance, not array of attributes as it would be. Any ideas?

Comment: `readObject()` is a wrapper for `PDOStatement::fetchObject()`, see https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchobject.php.

Comment: Why would you expect an array from `readObject()`. The whole purpose of this method is to create object and hydrate with query data. If you need raw array, you may use `Yii::app()->db->createCommand()/* ... */->queryAll()` and avoid using data reader at all.

Comment: I expect it to be array, because project which I currently maintain uses this schema in many places. And its working, it has been working for years. But recently I decided to add CTimestamp behavior (because newer version of mysql complains about default timestamp https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/issues/2993) and today I noticed fatalities in my calculation process. If I remove this behavior in response I will get array, believe me. In parallel will examine it again (using xdebug, and go step by step - I mean, I see all inheritance, all process)

Comment: That's weird, both `readObject()` and `PDOStatement::fetchObject()` returns object (or `false` on failure) according to documentation.